# Add location station in Nginx config file in Synology NAS

Tags: nginx, synology

I need to modify the nginx config file (/etc/nginx/app.d/server.webstation-vhost.conf) to add one line, which is for Laravel routing work correctly.

```
location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; }
```

The problem is  /etc/nginx/app.d/server.webstation-vhost.conf will ALWAYS OVERWITTEN once reboot the NAS,

Does anybody having experience how to hand this problem.

Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured this out, but if you haven't, under that vhost conf file (`/etc/nginx/app.d/server.webstation-vhost.conf`), look for something like:

```
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/conf.d/f2f0a62b-74d6-4c34-a745-d0156f13c9d6/user.conf*;
```

Instead of `f2f0a62b-74d6-4c34-a745-d0156f13c9d6` you should see another unique id for your nginx app, create/edit the mentioned `user.conf` file (without asterisk) with the contents you need, in my case I created a file with the contents below:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

Then I had to restart nginx with the command `sudo synoservice --restart nginx`.
And it worked.

PS.: I believe it should work for any DSM v6.1 or later (maybe 6.0.x as well).

---

For research I used:

- https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/122043
- https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/120538